# How to ignore a particular field from an Entity model upon insert?

Tags: .net, entity-framework

We have a field in our SQL Server database table which is autogenerated by SQL Server, the field is called `CreatedTime`.

We have mapped the whole  database table to our datamodel in Entity Framework, thus also the field `CreatedTime`.

When we insert a new row in the database, via Entity Framework, we thus do not provide any value for `CreatedTime`.

This causes the insert to fail with the error:

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM

So the question is: Is there is a way to to exclude a particular field in the Entity datamodel in the Entity Framework insert statement? So that we will not get the above error?

We would like to keep the field `CreatedTime` in the Entity model, because we might want to access it later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a simple solution to the problem on this thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/7db14342-b259-4973-ac09-93e183ae48bb

There Fernando Soto writes:

"If you go to the EDM designer click on the field in the table that is auto-generated by the database, right click on it and select Properties and 
look at the properties windows click on StoreGeneratedPattern and set its value to Computed, I believe it will give you what you are looking for."

The above solution was super quick and easy and it seems to work.

Also thank you for your contributions guys, but the above solution seems to do the job.

Comment: Will this persist after updating the model from database?

Answer (score 9):

If using Fluent API:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

this.Property(t => t.CreatedTime)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed);
```

If using Annotations

```
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Computed)]
public System.DateTime CreatedTime { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use NotMapped attribute on this property 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.notmappedattribute.aspx

Answer (score 1):

there are two things you can do:

1. If you have access to the database, check if the field has a `default` value. If it doesn't you can set it to `GETDATE()`, and the field should be set correctly, and you don't have to add/update it through Entity Framework.
2. If you don't have access to the database, or don't want to make any changes there, you can alter the behavior of the Entity Data Model to automatically set the date. Simply extend your ObjectContext model.

   ```
   public partial class MyEntities 
   {
       public override int SaveChanges() 
       {
           var entityChangeSet = ChangeTracker.Entries<SomeEntity>();
           if (entityChangeSet != null)
           {
               foreach (DbEntityEntry<SomeEntity> entry in entityChangeSet )
               {
                   switch (entry.State)
                   {
                       case EntityState.Modified:
                           entry.Entity.LastModifiedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                           break;
                       case EntityState.Added:
                           entry.Entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
                           break;
                   }
               }
           }
           return base.SaveChanges();
       }
   }
   ```

This way you don't have to add any information for those fields when you add or update an item, the model will do it for you. If you have multiple entities which need this behavior, you can create an interface and make the Entity classes inherit that:

```
public interface IHaveCreatedDate {
    DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}

public partial class MyEntity : IHaveCreatedDate {
    //MyEntity already implements this!
}
```

Then all you need to do is change the call to the ChangeTracker:

```
var entityChangeSet = ChangeTracker.Entries<IHaveCreatedDate>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Is *CreatedTime* nullable?

One possible workaround - if *CreatedTime* is NOT nullable:

```
DateTime sqlServerMinDateTime = new DateTime(1753, 1, 1, 12, 0, 1, 0);

if(myEntity.CreatedTime < sqlServerMinDateTime) 
{
    myEntity.CreatedTime = sqlServerMinDateTime;
}

// do insert here
// ....
```

One possible workaround - if *CreatedTime* is nullable:

```
DateTime sqlServerMinDateTime = new DateTime(1753, 1, 1, 12, 0, 1, 0);

if(myEntity.CreatedTime < sqlServerMinDateTime) 
{
    myEntity.CreatedTime = null;
}

// do insert here
// ....
```