# Insert values into database- Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Why this code doesn't work?
I want insert into database record with currently logged in user's UserName.

```cs
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateMeme(Memy memy)
        {
            var user=await GetCurrentUser();
            memy.Autor = user.UserName;
            memy.Like = 0;
            memy.Dislike = 0;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Memy.Add(memy);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            return View(memy);
        }
```

This is table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Memy] (
    [Id_mema] INT  IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [autor]   TEXT NULL,
    [like]    INT  NULL,
    [dislike] INT  NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id_mema] ASC)
);
```

I have 2 errors:
" Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Memy' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF"

And

"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details"

How to resolve this?

EDIT
Method `CreateMeme`

```cs
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateMeme(Memy memy)
        {
            var user=await GetCurrentUser();
            memy.Autor = user.UserName;
            memy.Like = 0;
            memy.Dislike = 0;
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Memy.Add(memy);
                _context.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });
            }

            return View(memy);
        }
```

Comment: Don't pass the identity column property to the Insert, it's telling you why it's a problem in your first error message. The database is setup to not allow custom values in your Identity column, as it appears it auto-increments.

Comment: Thanks, Without identity Id_mema will AutoNumber?

Comment: When you place this line `IDENTITY(1, 1)` it's telling the database to add 1 to the next insert as the `id_mema` value, you can exclude properties from insertion in entity framework in different ways, please see this article (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340142/how-to-ignore-a-particular-field-from-an-entity-model-upon-insert)

Comment: Why my way is wrong? I read on other forums and it should work

Comment: Did you read the article I posted in my previous comment? Your model I'm assuming has a property which relates to the identity column in your database table, you need to tell Entity Framework not to use that property when inserting. The article I linked you to has different approaches for excluding a model property from insert.

Answer (score 1):

If you are c# class to define your entities you might need to do something like this...

```
   public class Memy
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int Id_Mema { get; set; }
        public string Autor { get; set; }
```

Or if you are defining your entity attributes using fluent API you might need to do something like this;

```
 protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Memy>()
            .Property(p => p.Id_mema)
            .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }
```

This [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/valuegeneratedonadd-method) should have more information on using the Fluent API and [here](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/data-annotation-attributes/databasegenerated-attribute) for more information on decorating your POCOs with attributes to handle the auto-increment.

-HTH

Answer (score 0):

This error suggests the following:
Your Memy table is set to 'Is Identity' = 'True' with auto increment.
So you can't insert explict key values, which is logical.
Please check in your function, perhaps your method parameter object in `CreateMeme` has a value for `memy.Id_Mema`.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateMeme(Memy memy)
```

Make sure `memy.Id_Mema` is not assigned by your code explicitly.
Hope this helps.